# C# Failed to change {name} property of user control

Tags: c#, winforms

When I tried to change the {name} property of the user controls on the form, the below error occurs:

[image]

And here's the "selectedVal" property on "ddlPriority" user control
[image]

Here's the ddlPriority_Load function

```
  Scheduler.DAL.TableClass.Priority pri = new Scheduler.DAL.TableClass.Priority();
            combxPriority.DataSource = pri.selectPriorities();
            combxPriority.DisplayMember = "name";
            combxPriority.ValueMember = "PriorityID";
            Scheduler.DAL.TableClass.Settings set = new Scheduler.DAL.TableClass.Settings();
            if (set.thisTable != null)
                combxPriority.SelectedValue = set.thisTable.DefaultPriorityID;
```

The ddlPriority user control is just a combo box.

How can I solve this problem?

---

Edited:

Below is the selectPriorities method:

properties.cs

```
public static string DBConnection = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["DB_Connection"];
```

Priority.cs

```
public DataTable selectPriorities()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(properties.DBConnection);
            con.Open();
            string sqlQuery = "select name, PriorityID from Priority";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con);
            SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            dt.Load(read);
            read.Close();
            con.Close();
            return dt;
        }
```

Comment: Can you also post the code from pri.selectPriorities(); ? I think this is returning null at design time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `combxPriority.SelectedValue` is `null` (no line is selected) and that's why `combxPriority.SelectedValue.ToString()` throws the exception.
You have to make sure `combxPriority.SelectedValue` is not null before accessing it.

Comment: I've added a checking to check whether the datasource is null, the selectedValue is null, the object is null and the dropdownlist is null, but the result is still the same.. by the way, I haven't run the program yet, why visual studio managed to get the data from Database before I run the program?

Comment: You should use `if (!this.DesignMode)` for code you don't want to run in design time. see http://dotnetfacts.blogspot.co.il/2009/01/identifying-run-time-and-design-mode.html